# Recent firefox and the webshim implementation of details

Tags: html, firefox, webshim

Recent releases of Firefox (e.g. 49.0) implement the details tag. Unfortunately this is partially not compatible with the webshim implementation of details. The black triangle disappears although the content of the summary tag is still visible and clicking it still hides and shows the content of details.

This can be seen in https://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/#DetailsSummary

Any known workaround? Due to IE and Edge this polyfill is still useful.

Answer (score 0):

I should have googled a little longer.

A partial workaround is adding to your CSS

```
details summary {
   display: list-item !important;
}
```

Additional information can be found here:

https://gist.github.com/ericclemmons/b146fe5da72ca1f706b2ef72a20ac39d

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1283989

https://github.com/StylishThemes/GitHub-Dark/commit/20c524d2fe59d874afcd675f0e9e01b23cefd35a

Comment: normalize.css also might be relevant. Use normalize.css v. 5 or later. See https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/issues/604